# React Snackbar Compnent from notistack not able to handle long text in its GUI as the text goes out in case of small window size

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, snackbar, notistack

I am new to React UI Libraries like material-ui and notistack. In my project Components like  are being used with some styling/css. In the whole react application when there is a long dynamic text that is put inside this Snackbar component its GUI gets disturbed and the text cut offs and goes out of the component. How can i habndle this and make it responsive so that it can handle very long texts inside it.

Following is the code for the Snackbar Component in file SanckbarProvider.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {
  SnackbarProvider as NisSnackbarProvider,
  SnackbarProviderProps,
} from "notistack";

import { Fade } from "@material-ui/core";
import { TransitionProps } from "@material-ui/core/transitions";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { CloseButton } from "./CloseButton";


const variantStyle = (color: string, backgroundColor: string) => ({
  height: "36px;",
  color: `${color} !important`,
  backgroundColor: `${backgroundColor} !important`,
  opacity: "0.95 !important",
  borderRadius: "3px;",
  boxShadow: "0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);",
  alignContent: "center",
  marginRight: "-4px !important",
});

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  success: variantStyle("#3AA658", "#BBE9B6"),
  error: variantStyle("#FFFFFF", "#D07B7B"),
  warning: variantStyle("#FFFFFF", "#EC9E4D"),
  info: variantStyle("#FFFFFF", "#6da4d0"),
}));

const FadeTransition = (props: TransitionProps) => <Fade {...props}/>;

const SnackbarProvider = ({ children }: SnackbarProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <NisSnackbarProvider
      classes={{
        variantSuccess: classes.success,
        variantError: classes.error,
        variantWarning: classes.warning,
        variantInfo: classes.info,
      }}
      action={key => <CloseButton id={key} />}
      maxSnack={7}
      anchorOrigin={{vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "right"}}
      autoHideDuration={3000}
      transitionDuration={{enter: 1000, exit: 500}}
      TransitionComponent={FadeTransition}
      variant={"success"}
      preventDuplicate
    >
      {children}
    </NisSnackbarProvider>
  );
};

export default SnackbarProvider;
```

And this is for main app component in App.tsx

```
const ContentWrapper = styled.div<WrapperProps>`
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: ${(props) => (props.showBackground ? "white" : "transparent")};
  height: calc(100vh);
`;

const LinearProgressWrapper = styled.div`
 position: absolute;
 top: ${LINEAR_PROGRESS_TOP_POSITION};
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
`;

const LinearProgressStyled = styled(LinearProgress)`
  height: 6px;
`;

const App = (): JSX.Element => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const size = useScreenSize();
  const loginState = useSelector(loginSelector);
  const showLoadingIndicator = useSelector(pendingApiCallsExist);
  const { authenticated } = loginState;
  const selectedScreen = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.ui.view);

  const shouldShowBigTopbar = !!(selectedScreen === ViewTypes.WorkspacesList && IS_MAC_OS);

  // for some reasons, after logout, sizesReducer is reset.
  // So it's needed to manually trigger recalculation
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (size.height !== -1) {
      dispatch(resizeAction(size));
    }
  }, [authenticated, dispatch, size]);

  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={maTheme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={maTheme}>
          <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <SnackbarProvider>
              <Socket url={SOCKET_URL}/>
              <ContentWrapper
                showBackground={shouldShowBigTopbar}
              >
                <Router history={routerHistory}>
                  <Routes />
                  {showLoadingIndicator && <LinearProgressWrapper>
                    <LinearProgressStyled />
                  </LinearProgressWrapper>}
                  <SnackbarsList />
                </Router>
              </ContentWrapper>
            </SnackbarProvider>
          </I18nextProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This the the code for rendering the info and moreinfo snackbar

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardActions,
  Collapse,
  IconButton,
  Paper,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

import { SnackbarMessage, useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import { autoUpdater } from "electron-updater";

const infoBase = {
  alignContent: "center",
  backgroundColor: "#D07B7B",
  borderRadius: "3px;",
  boxShadow: "0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  marginRight: "-4px",
  opacity: "0.95",
  padding: "6px 16px",
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    marginRight: "-4px",
    maxWidth: 440,
    minWidth: 344,
  },
  info: {
    ...infoBase,
    height: "36px",
  },
  icons: {
    marginLeft: "auto !important",
    marginRight: "-8px",
    paddingLeft: "16px",
  },
  expand: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    padding: "8px 8px",
    transform: "rotate(0deg)",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)",
  },
  moreInfo: {
    ...infoBase,
    maxHeight: "156px",
    overflowWrap: "break-word",
  },
}));

interface IProps {
  id: string | number,
  info: string,
  moreInfo: string,
}

const MoreInfoSnackbar = (props: IProps): JSX.Element => {
  const {id, info, moreInfo} = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => setExpanded(!expanded);
  const handleDismiss = () => closeSnackbar(id);

  // TODO: What the heck to do with this? - very, very hacky!
  const renderErrorIcon = () => (
    <svg className="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 28 28"
      aria-hidden="true"
      style={{fontSize: "20px", marginInlineEnd: "8px"}}
    >
      <path
        d="M12,2C17.53,2 22,6.47 22,12C22,17.53 17.53,22 12,22C6.47,22 2,17.53 2,12C2,6.47 6.47,2 12,2M15.59,7L12,10.59L8.41,7L7,8.41L10.59,12L7,15.59L8.41,17L12,13.41L15.59,17L17,15.59L13.41,12L17,8.41L15.59,7Z">
      </path>
    </svg>
  );

  const renderActionIcons = () => (
    <div className={classes.icons}>
      <IconButton
        style={{
          transform: expanded ? "rotate(180deg)" : "",
        }}
        aria-label="Show more"
        className={classes.expand}
        onClick={handleExpandClick}
      >
        <ExpandMoreIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton className={classes.expand} onClick={handleDismiss}>
        <CloseIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );

  const renderInfo = () => (
    <CardActions className={classes.info}>
      {renderErrorIcon()}
      <Typography gutterBottom>
        {info}
      </Typography>
      {renderActionIcons()}
    </CardActions>
  );

  const renderMoreInfo = () => (
    <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
      <Paper className={classes.moreInfo}>
        <Typography gutterBottom>
          {moreInfo}
        </Typography>
      </Paper>
    </Collapse>
  );

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      {renderInfo()}
      {renderMoreInfo()}
    </Card>
  );
};

type IErrors = {
  info: string
  moreInfo: string
}

const processMessage = (message: React.ReactNode): IErrors => {
  if (typeof message === "string") {
    return {info: message, moreInfo: ""};
  }
  if (Array.isArray(message)) {
    const info = typeof message[0] === "string" ? message[0] : "";
    const moreInfo = typeof message[1] === "string" ? message[1] : "";
    return {info, moreInfo};
  }
  return {info: "", moreInfo: ""};
};

/**
 This is the set callback signature that notistack allows for returning
 a customized snackbar.

 It is not straightforward to get more data into the custom snackbar.
 So we leverage the message param. It can be a string or an array.
 We could use a JSON string and then parse it to get a bunch more options
 but for now, we are just adding an extra "moreInfo" string

 Works with a message array of [message, moreInfo], I.e:
 import { getMoreInfoSnackbar } from "../../snacks/MoreInfoSnackbar";
 ...
 enqueueSnackbar(
   ["something went wrong", "More detailed info, accessed via dropdown"],
   {
      content: getMoreInfoSnackbar,
      persist: true,
    },
 );
 */
export const getMoreInfoSnackbar = (key: React.ReactText, message: React.ReactNode): SnackbarMessage => {
  const {info, moreInfo} = processMessage(message);
  return <MoreInfoSnackbar id={key} info={info} moreInfo={moreInfo}/>;
};
export default MoreInfoSnackbar;
```

Can someone help to resolve this issue as mentioned above? How can a make this snackbar component resize/grow with the content inside it and adjsut and align the content fit ito it.

[Snackbar Component Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqqRe.png)

Comment: To increase the chance that someone will help you, please create a working snippet (using codesandbox or similar) which reproduces the issue and includes only the minimal relevant code (actionIcons for example are not relevant).